# Combining two sentences with a "subject verb-ing" clause

Tags: grammar

Is this sentence correct? "2020 has passed, another journey ending".  If so, what is the grammatical term for "another journey ending"? If not, how can I fix it without sacrificing its conciseness too much? Thanks.

Comment: Does "another journey" correspond to 2020?

Comment: Yes, "another journey" does correspond to 2020

Comment: In which case, since it states that "2020 has passed" shouldn't it be "another journey has ended"?